# Send Data between Activities as done with fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a data of custom List type (finalHolder.data)

Earlier I had to send this data to a Fragment constructor it is working fine

```
  Fragment fragment;
                fragment = new RouteMap(finalHolder.data);
                ((Activity)getContext()).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment).commit();
```

The Fragment constructor code

```
public RouteMap() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public RouteMap(MyListEntity data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

Activity constructor :

```
 public Map() {

}

public Map(MyListEntity data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

But now I want this same data to reach a Activity (Map2)

I tried putExtra with intent but Intent but it doesnt work

In Short I want the "finalHolder.data" to be send to Activity constructor while calling it .

If it isnt possible then please suggest solution 
Thanks

Comment: You probably need to serialize your list and use intent.putSerializable.

Comment: If you agreed for any of the answer please accept.

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to use Activity constructor. To send data object to activity you can use Intent extras with Parcelable. For that you need to do the follow way.

1. Implement your data class from Parcelable

   Ex: MyListEntity implements Parcelable
2. Override the following methods in your data class(MyListEntity) writeToParcel(), readFromParcel()

3.Implement the CREATOR class in your data class(MyListEntity)

**Reference link for Parcelable example:** [passing object to activity](http://karanbalkar.com/2014/01/tutorial-67-passing-data-between-activities-using-parcelable/)

4. Send the data object using Intent as mentioned below

> ```
> Intent i = new Intent(this,Activity(Map2).class);
>
> i.putExtra("mylistdata",finalHolder.data);
>
> startActivity(i);
> ```

5. And finally get the same data at your Activity(Map2) onCreate() method as mentioned below

> ```
> MyListEntity listEntry = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("mylistdata");
> ```

Now your object is ready at your second activity.
 Hope this will help for you.

Answer (score 0):

To send an object in intent the object's class must be serializable so make your 
MyListEntity implements serializable then use the Intent's `putExtra(String name, Serializable value)` and in the other activity use the intent's `getSerializableExtra (String name)` but don't forget to cast the returned value

Answer (score 0):

One option could be letting your custom class implement the Serializable interface and then you can pass object instances in the intent extra using the putExtra(Serializable..) variant of the Intent#putExtra() method.

Your data should implement Serializable ie

```
MyListEntity implements Serializable
```

//Use this to send the data

```
intent.putExtra("MyClass", finalHolder.data);
```

// To retrieve object in second Activity

```
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyClass");
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your Fragment: it is not smart to pass data via c-tor to fragments! 
Use arguments mechanism:

```
Fragment f = new SomeFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putExtra("data", someData);
f.setArguments(args);
```

And retreive them:

```
getArguments().getParcelableExtra("data")
```

More info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

But (to return to your question), for that, your data have to implement Serialisable (Java approach) or, by Google advised Parcelable (Android style)

More info about Parcelable [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).
Implementing Parcelable interface can be boring and error prone, so some cool people created this: http://www.parcelabler.com/